# i fetched an api data and put in and object of a state , and iwant to sort that fetched array , and display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, fetch

I have fetched a json api data within an url,  and put in a array of a state and i want to sort that array by id and display it and display ordered list into the console.log but it dos not not display and sorted.

Here is my code :

```
//the class with state 
class ProductsideBar extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props) 
     this.state= {
        cat:[],
    }
}
```

//  i have two functions for fetch and sorting

```
      //fetchCategory function--------------------- 
      fetchCategory = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost/wpsedighgroup/wp-json/wp/v2/mahsoolat-sanati)
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then((res) => {
           this.setState = {
            cat:res  
      })
};

//sort function--------------------- 
       sortCategory = () => {
        console.log('state cat is  : ' , this.state.cat)
        const catSOrted = this.state.cat.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);
        console.log('Ordered is  : ' , catSOrted )
     } 




//lifeCycle function--------------------- 
   componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchCategory();
    this.sortCategory ();
    // this.fetchSubcategory();

} 



//render----
  render () {
      return(
         <Grid  fluid >
          <Col className='side_bar'>
            <div>     
              {this.state.cat.map(  cat  => {
               return (
                <ul>
                 <Link to={`/Categories/${cat.name}`}><h1>{cat.id}</h1></Link> 
                     </li>  
                </ul>
                            )
                          })}
                 </div>           
    export default Prodcuts....
```

Comment: Is it not displayed or is it just not sorted ?

Comment: both of them ,, not sorting and not displayed

Comment: It should be `this.setState({....})` not `this.setState = {....}`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting state wrong way. Try `setState({cat: res}, some_callback_function)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change what is in your `state` without `setState`, even just sorting it. I would recommend sorting your array right after fetching it.

Your `setState` syntax is also incorrect, this function expects a JSON object :

```
fetchCategory = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost/wpsedighgroup/wp-json/wp/v2/mahsoolat-sanati')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                cat: res.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)
            })
        })
};
```

And then just deleting your `sortCategory` function.

The JSX in your `render` also had an incorrect syntax, here is a coorect one :

```
render() {
    return (
        <Grid fluid >
            <Col className='side_bar'>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                    {this.state.cat.map(cat => 
                        <li>
                            <Link to={`/Categories/${cat.name}`}><h1>{cat.id}</h1></Link> 
                        </li> 
                    )} 
                    </ul>
                </div> 
            </Col>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```